# Apache - Recursively redirect sub directory and all child content

Tags: apache, redirect, httpd.conf

I am trying to recursively redirect a sub directory and all child content that resides within that sub directory.

Suppose I have a sub directory `/foo/bar` such that it presents as `http://www.example.com/foo/bar`. I would like to redirect this sub directory and all pages and directories that reside within it to `/bar` such that it presents itself as `http://www.example.com/bar`. So when someone visits `http://www.example.com/foo/bar` they are redirected to `http://www.example.com/bar`.

This needs to apply recursively as well, so pages such as the following...

- `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/butterfly.html`
- `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/donkey/shrek.html`
- `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/elephant/apple/peanut.html`

...all redirect to the following.

- `http://www.example.com/bar/butterfly.html`
- `http://www.example.com/bar/donkey/shrek.html`
- `http://www.example.com/bar/elephant/apple/peanut.html`

Is there any way to do this without individually specifying each page I want to redirect? I understand how to do that at the very least as a fallback, but it would be much more convenient to have one line and not have to worry about 30+ some odd pages that I need to redirect individually.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved with a Redirect directive

A simple redirect like this will do:

```
Redirect /foo/bar /bar
```

Oh and here is the link for the Directive Documentation in the official docs:
[Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)